# Auto refresh layer data on ArcGIS

Tags: excel, xml, csv, arcgis

I'm trying to get data to auto refresh on a map layer I have added on ArcGIS. The information shows up just fine but does not refresh automatically as it does on the web page.

I have tried converting from its original source (XML on a web page updating every 15 minutes) to Excel, CSV (Both also update just fine) as well as trying to pull from Google Drive. I should mention I am using a free trial to test this program out so there's probably a little handcuffing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a method that resolved my own issue. ArcGIS Onlines auto update/refresh apparently only works for layers published by ArcGIS. Got around this by saving my CSV file to google drive and modifying the shareable link. [process shown here](https://solvemethod.com/google-drive-direct-link/)  I then added the layer from web by using the modified link from Google Drive. Now the data on my map updates with whatever was last saved on the spreadsheet at the refresh interval I set.